# How to split argument to `bash -c` on multiple lines?

Tags: bash

I have a very long command I need to pass to bash via -c, e.g. `'/bin/bash' '-c' 'my long command'` (it's called as an array by something like python's subprocess (but not python)).

Is there anyway I can split `'my long command'` onto multiple lines? I've tried 

`'my\
long\
command'`
 
but it didn't work.

Comment: actually it should work just use spaces around \

Comment: I tried that too, but still no joy. If that's the advertised functionality perhaps its the runner that's messing it up :-/

Comment: Can you show the actual code where you tried that?  And describe what kind of "not work" you get?  There's nothing wrong with (e.g.) `execl("/bin/bash", "bash", "-c", "my\\\nlong\\\ncommand")` so unless your command is too long for `exec` (in which case you should be streaming it as input), your problem is with your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if the resulting string argument must be one-line, it can be formed concatenating quoted strings and use  backslash newline, to format them on multiple lines

```
echo 'a very very ...'\
'long string'
```

note that trailing and leading spaces outside quoted string are significant and are used to split arguments.

The following commands also works

```
bash -c 'echo \
hello'
```

because the bash process spawned handles the sequence.

```
bash -c "echo \
hello"
```

because the current bash process the lines between double quotes are joined.

what is the exact command that doesn't work ?

Comment: You're right. It was the runner that wasn't working. The command was embedded in yaml.